# PHP date("w", $timein) returns wrong value with a valid date

Tags: php, date, output

I have this function that runs on the server and I want a different output based on the day of the week, Saturday and Sunday should give weekend message and different for the weekdays.

```
$timein = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$dw = date("D", $timein);
$tm = date("e", $timein);
echo "Current Date: ".$timein."<br>";
echo "Day of the week: ".$dw."<br>";
echo "Timezone: ".$tm."<br>";
```

and this is the output:

> Current Date: 2015-05-15 06:07:12
>  Day of the week: Wed
>   Timezone: America/Denver

We are Friday and I was expecting `Fri`, I was using `w` instead of `D` but I always was getting 3 in the results.

Comment: `date()` does not return a timestamp, so `$timein` is totally wrong when used in `$dw` and `$tm`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use **[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)** function to convert it into a Unix timestamp. Just update your code into.

```
$dw = date("D", strtotime($timein));
$tm = date("e", strtotime($timein));
```